# Can I generate an array with both negative and positive numbers and specify the limits and the dimension of this array?

Tags: python, numpy, random

`c=np.random.rand(10,2)` generates an array of random numbers from in `[0,1)`. Can I generate the same array (in terms of size) but with negative AND positive numbers? Moreover, can I choose the limits and the dimension of this array? for example if I want from -2 to 2.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: So should those values be floating point values between -2 and 2, or integers?

Comment: See `numpy.random.uniform`, e.g. `c = numpy.random.uniform(low=-2, high=2, size=(10, 2))`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `np.random.randint` and pass the `size` parameter. For values in `[-2, 2)` and size `(10, 2)` you have:

```
In [32]: np.random.randint(-2, 2, (10, 2))
Out[32]:
array([[-1,  1],
       [-2,  0],
       [-1,  0],
       [-2, -2],
       [ 0, -2],
       [-2, -2],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 1, -1],
       [ 0,  1],
       [-2, -1]])
```

Or use `np.random.uniform` for floats:

```
In [33]: size = (10, 2)

In [39]: np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size)
Out[39]:
array([[-1.1129566 , -1.94562947],
       [ 0.21356557, -1.96769933],
       [ 1.1481992 , -0.08494563],
       [ 0.12561175,  0.95580417],
       [-1.79335536, -1.01276994],
       [ 1.56808971,  0.15911181],
       [ 0.50987451, -1.39039728],
       [-1.57962641,  1.59555514],
       [-1.8318709 , -1.57055885],
       [ 0.682527  , -1.89022731]])
```

Comment: This only generates *integers*, I think the OP wanted floats.

Comment: Granted, not sure what I based that on now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added some code that can help them get floats from those

Comment: @MartijnPieters Brainfart on that. Was trying to retrofit the first answer to match the float requirement

Comment: Take into account `uniform` is half-open; you *can* produce `-2`, but never `2`. You could use `-2 + sys.float_info.epsilon` to 'open' the start..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes thanks for suggesting that workaround. I indicated the half openness with `[-2, 2)` in the answer.

Comment: I need to generate an array `n x n` with negative values between `-0.35` and `-0.30`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to generate uniform numbers from a normal distribution you could get a random number between 0 and 1, and the use that to build your random number between the min and max.

```
(np.random.rand(30) * 10) - 5
```

The above will give 30 numbers between [-5, +5)

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered, I'd like to add one more way. You can use `np.linspace` for generating equally spaced floats within a specified range like:

```
>>> nums = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)
>>> nums
array([-2.        , -1.55555556, -1.11111111, -0.66666667, -0.22222222,
        0.22222222,  0.66666667,  1.11111111,  1.55555556,  2.        ])
```

If required, you can then reshape the array to any compatible desired shape.

```
>>> nums.reshape(5, 2)
array([[-2.        , -1.55555556],
       [-1.11111111, -0.66666667],
       [-0.22222222,  0.22222222],
       [ 0.66666667,  1.11111111],
       [ 1.55555556,  2.        ]])
```

Read more in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) about optional and required parameters.